# Summing up two columns of pandas dataframe ignoring NaN

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ORDER':["A", "A"], 'col1':[np.nan, np.nan], 'col2':[np.nan, 5]})
df

    ORDER   col1    col2
0    A      NaN     NaN
1    A      NaN     5.0
```

I want to create a column 'new' as sum(col1, col2) ignoring Nan only if one of the column as Nan,
If both of the columns have NaN value, it should return NaN as below

I tried the below code and it works fine. Is there any way to achieve the same with just one line of code.

```
df['new'] = df[['col1', 'col2']].sum(axis = 1)
df['new'] = np.where(pd.isnull(df['col1']) & pd.isnull(df['col2']), np.nan, df['new'])
df
    ORDER   col1    col2    new
0    A      NaN      NaN    NaN
1    A      NaN      5.0    5.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do `sum` with `min_count`

```
df['new'] = df[['col1','col2']].sum(axis=1,min_count=1)
Out[78]: 
0    NaN
1    5.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `add` function on the two columns, which takes a `fill_value` argument that lets you replace `NaN`:

```
df['col1'].add(df['col2'], fill_value=0) 

0    NaN
1    5.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Yes it will: "`fill_value`: Fill existing missing (NaN) values, and any new element needed for successful DataFrame alignment, with this value before computation. If data in both corresponding DataFrame locations is missing the result will be missing."

Answer (score 0):

Is this ok?

```
df['new'] = df[['col1', 'col2']].sum(axis = 1).replace(0,np.nan)
```

Comment: What if all (or at least one) numbers in a row are `0`?

Comment: Will turn in to NaN